# Remove highlighting box from edit field

Tags: blackberry, textbox, blackberry-editfield

I am using edit field to enter some text. When I click on edit field, one **Highlighting box** is showing as in image. I want to hide that box. Please catch the problem using below image:

[image]

How to remove this *focused box* in edit field??

Answer (score 1):

As it's Edit Field, its default nature is to highlight text for editing. If you are going to enter values in the field during application runtime means you have to bare this. If you are going to enter values programatically means use Rich Text Field or your

```
editfield.setEditable(false);
```

Comment: I want to make it editable, because I am going to type some values here.

Ok, can you give me one more idea: "Is there any way to get status whether this highlighting box is appearing or not??"